# Login with either email or username and ignore upper/lower cases for UserName during login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I'm wokring in a Asp.Net MVC5 web app with EntityFramework 6.
I added the UserName attribute to the AspNetUser db table, more exactly I made the UserName to be user chosen, not to be the email.

But in this tutorial [ASP.NET Identity 2.0.0 – UserName and Email separation](http://marcinjuraszek.com/2014/03/asp-net-identity-2-0-0-username-and-email-separation.html)
it says: "although login page requires an email address to log in it actually uses model.UserName to validate provided email.". So why does it require the UserName even while it says it's using the Email property, where is that rule being setup and where/how can I change it?

And more important: How can I make the login to work with either email or username like in facebook and also to ignore upper/lowercases during login?

Edited; the code changes I made:

I added this property in the RegisterViewModel

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "UserName")]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Added this code in the Register view:

```
<!-- (...) -->
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control " })
</div>
</div>
<!-- (...) -->
```

Changed the Register action method to use the also UserName when creating a new user:

```
// (...)
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email };
// (...)
```

Replaced the Email attribute in the LoginViewModel with:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "User Name")]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

And also in the login view I replaced the Email with UserName:

```
<!-- (...) -->
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- (...) -->
```

And also changed the Login action method to use the UserName instead of the Email to login:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return View(model);
}

// This doesn't count login failures towards lockout only two factor authentication
// To enable password failures to trigger lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
var result = await SignInHelper.PasswordSignIn(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
switch (result)
{
// (...)
```

Comment: identity uses username and pass word to authenticate user. You can store the user's email address in the username field as the username for the user. if you have both a username and an email address then you can simply search for the user using either the name or email and then if one is found, try to authenticate the user with the username and password.

Comment: can you show me with an example please. cuz how I said, even when the ViewModel is set to use the Email property, it will expect the username as login credential. So please give me an example with code. @Nkosi

Comment: Show what you tried and I'll make my suggestions from there.

Comment: I don't write code to show you what I did, cuz I followed every step of the tutorial... There was also a link that said how to user Email and Username for login but it shows a 404 error code @Nkosi 
here is the link again
 http://marcinjuraszek.com/2014/03/asp-net-identity-2-0-0-username-and-email-separation.html

Comment: I asked for the code example to adhere to [mcve]. I must now go site and ready article to help you. Those willing to help you can use example you provide to find a solution for you.

Comment: @Nkosi I added the code in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are comfortable with making and additional call to the database in the case of it being an email address, here is an example of what you can try.

```cs
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        string username = model.UserName;
        ApplicationUser user = null;
        // CHECK FOR EMAIL
        if(IsValidEmail(username)) {
            user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(username);
            if(user != null) username = user.UserName;
            else {
                // If user with email address does not exists, here is a good place
                // to exit as we have already ascertained that the user is not in the system
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid user name or password provided.") 
                return View(model); 
            }                
        }
        // END CHECK FOR EMAIL
        user = await userManager.FindAsync(username, model.Password);
        if (user != null) {
            var result = await SignInHelper.PasswordSignIn(username, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
            switch (result) {
                //...code removed for brevity
            }
        } else {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid user name or password provided.") 
        }

    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, re-display form
    return View(model);
}

private static bool IsValidEmail(string email) {
    string MatchEmailPattern =
       @"^(([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\w-]{2,}))@" +
       @"((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\." +
       @"([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|" +
       @"([a-zA-Z]+[\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$";

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email)) {
        string pattern = MatchEmailPattern;
        return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(email, pattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are ignorin the upper/lowercase only for email? And by the way, can you provide me a regex to allow the username to be only alphabets and numbers when I create or edit the USerName, no symbols or space?

Comment: Finding user by email or username is not case sensitive.

Comment: As for the regex you don't need it. You can configure that when you configure your `UserManager` by setting `UserManager.UserValidator.AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = true;`

Comment: Then why did you made the bool method IsValidEmail()?

Comment: To confirm that the value is a well formatted email address. If it is then clearly the user is trying to authenticate with an email address so I'll search for the user using email address. Other wise check using entered value as normal username.

Comment: But Asp.Net MVC by default checks if it's a valid email address or not!!! Is this method really needed? (sorry, now I'm being ignorant)

Comment: This is to avoid it throwing an exception when the email is not valid. One less expensive exception to catch. Again it is more so you know it is an email so you know to then search for the user by email not username. the value entered could be anything.

Comment: oh now I get it. We need it cuz we changed the LoginViewModel to use Username for login instead of email (I totally forgot the validation check will be different). Should we add back the email attribute in the LoginViewModel?

Comment: No. because you want the login to be able to accept both email and non-email values. If you put back the validation then it will only accept email values

Comment: and one last thing before I run the project. where to configure the UserManager by setting UserManager.UserValidator.AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = true; ?

Comment: look for your `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` derived class.

Comment: Ok, sorry, it's kinda late here, and I spend my whole day with this stuff, so my eyes are playing games with me now. I suggest you to visit the Asp.Net forum and help the guys in need there ;)

Comment: Getting red lines at `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` saying the name does not exist in the current context, and the only fix is to generate a method!!!!

Comment: Typo. should be `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`

Comment: One problem: the `result` hits Success, when I check with the debugger, but then instead of loging in with email, it gives an invalid login attempt error

Comment: No don't login with email. You use the email to find the user and then use the username from the found user to login. Identity only uses the username to login. You are letting your user enter their email so you can find username and then use that to log them in. are you following the code liek i have in my example? you notice how I pass the username value that I get from user found by email.

Comment: Yeah I know that, but I wanted to say that when I type the email this is what happens. Cuz it checks if there is a user with that email and from that user it gets the UserName to login

Comment: is copy paste enough followed :P yeah everything is like your code. except where you shorten the code there is the full switch statement

Comment: but it doesn't! the `result` var hits success then when it gets inside the switch it hits failure!!!

Comment: ohh now I see my error. I still use `model.UserName` instead of `username`